# run python script and specifying answers to the prompt questions

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a python script which I can Only run, not modify.

While execution, via terminal one has to type "Y" or "N" as an answer to 1 question.

Is there a way to run/execute a python script with specifying the answer on it in advance?

I am aware that whenever this is possible one should rather make a respective option in a script to avoid this issues.

Comment: `yes | yourscript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `printf` built-in alone in `bash`

```
printf "yes\n" | <yourscript>
```

As requested in the comments,

```
printf "yes\nCatDog\nno\n"
```

Comment: just from curiosity: if there were several different replies needed, how would this be modified?

Comment: @greyxray: sever replies of `yes`/`no` or any custom string?

Comment: both, for example, if one would like to pass "yes", "CatDog", "no" in this sequence